# How can I pass PDF special to dvisvgm?

Tags: dvisvgm, specials

From dvisvgm documentation:

```
SUPPORTED SPECIALS
       dvisvgm supports several special commands that enrich the DVI command set with additional
       instructions for features, like color, graphics, and hyperlinks. The term special command,
       or just special, originates from the TeX command \special{...} which does almost nothing.

[...]

       dvisvgm
           dvisvgm offers its own small set of specials. The following list gives a brief
           overview.

           dvisvgm:raw text
               Adds an arbitrary sequence of XML nodes to the page section of the SVG document.
               dvisvgm checks syntax and proper nesting of the inserted elements but does not
               perform any validation, thus the user has to ensure that the resulting SVG is
               still valid. Opening and closing tags may be distributed among different raw
               specials. The tags themselves can also be split but must be continued with the
               immediately following raw special. Both syntactically incorrect and wrongly nested
               tags lead to error messages. Parameter text may also contain the expressions {?x},
               {?y}, {?color}, and {?matrix} that expand to the current x or y coordinate, the
               current color, and current transformation matrix, respectively. Character sequence
               {?nl} expands to a newline character. Finally, constructions of the form {?(expr)}
               enable the evaluation of mathematical expressions which may consist of basic
               arithmetic operations including modulo. Like above, the variables x and y
               represent the current coordinates. Example: {?(-10*(x+2y)-5)}.
```

If I compile the following TeX file to DVI, then use dvisvgm to convert it to SVG:

```tex
\pdfoutput=0
\pdfcompresslevel=0
\pdfobjcompresslevel=0
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[active, tightpage]{preview}
\usepackage{tikz}
\pagenumbering{gobble}
\begin{document}
\begin{preview}
\special{dvisvgm:raw <g id='abc'>}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw (0,0) circle (1);
\end{tikzpicture}
\special{dvisvgm:raw </g>}
\end{preview}
\end{document}
```

→

```bash
dvisvgm --output=main.svg main.dvi
```

Then the SVG output is:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<!-- This file was generated by dvisvgm 3.1.2 -->
<svg version='1.1' xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg' xmlns:xlink='http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink' width='57.0899pt' height='57.0899pt' viewBox='-.00005 -57.08985 57.0899 57.0899'>
<g id='page1'>
<g id='abc'>
<path d='M56.8906-28.546875C56.8906-44.2031 44.2031-56.8906 28.546875-56.8906C12.8906-56.8906 .1992-44.2031 .1992-28.546875C.1992-12.8906 12.8906-.1992 28.546875-.1992C44.2031-.1992 56.8906-12.8906 56.8906-28.546875Z' stroke='#000' fill='none' stroke-width='.3985'/>
</g>
</g>
</svg>
```

Important part is that the groups named `abc` is included in the output.

Now I try to do the same thing, but pass through PDF:

```tex
\pdfoutput=1
\pdfcompresslevel=0
\pdfobjcompresslevel=0
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[active, tightpage]{preview}
\usepackage{tikz}
\pagenumbering{gobble}
\begin{document}
\begin{preview}
\special{pdf:dvisvgm:raw <g id='abc'>}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw (0,0) circle (1);
\end{tikzpicture}
\special{pdf:dvisvgm:raw </g>}
\end{preview}
\end{document}
```

The specials are included in the PDF as expected:

```
%PDF-1.5
%ÐÔÅØ
6 0 obj
<<
/Length 392       
>>
stream
1 0 0 1 0.5 57.591 cm
dvisvgm:raw <g id='abc'>
1 0 0 1 28.546 -28.545 cm
q 
0 G 
0 g 
0.3985 w 
q 
0.0 0.0 m
```

Then I convert the SVG to PDF:

```bash
dvisvgm --pdf --output=main.svg main.pdf
```

but the SVG does not contain the desired tags.

Question: **is it possible to do a TeX → PDF → SVG compilation, and specify raw SVG tag in the TeX source code to be inserted into the final SVG file** (just like what I did in the TeX → DVI → SVG compilation)?

Comment: sorry but why do you want "to fix" that?

Comment: what do you want to happen??? why do you want  literal dvisvgm instructions embedded in the pdf? how do you intend to extract the instructions from a pdf an pass to dvisvgm????

Comment: `pdf:dvisvgm:raw <g id='abc'>}` is basically a syntax error as the argument isn't pdf, but it is not reported as tex does not syntax check specials

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Maybe I wasn't clear on the question, edited.

Comment: how do you go from pdf to svg?

Comment: @UlrikeFischer Sorry, fixed.

Comment: sorry yes I deleted that comment as I re-read your question, as far as I can tell --pdf is a thin wrapper around gs or mutool that actually does a pdf to svg conversion, the manual lists a very small set of specials supported mostly pdf:mapline controling font access I don't think you (or dvisvgm) have any real control over the generated svg in that case,

Comment: "currently, only pdf:mapﬁle, pdf:mapline, pdf:pagesize, and PDF hyperlink
specials are supported by dvisvgm."

Comment: the pdf specials are recognized by dvisvgm if you go the route through DVI. If you convert a PDF they are irrelevant. Then it only matters what the ghostscript/mutool converted does with a PDF.